# Concatenate selected values from array of strings

Tags: perl

I have this Array:

`my @List = (
    "AB,CD,EF",
    "GH,IJ",
    "KL,MN,OP,UV",
    "WX",
    "YZ,123,456,789",
);`

And by getting a list of numbers from user

`for example: 0 3 4`

I want to create a new string by concatenate just the relevant strings from my List.
for the example above the new string will be:

`"AB,CD,EF,WX,YZ,123,456,789"`

Any help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `join` together with a *slice* of the `@list` array. A global regex match will serve to extract all the numbers from an input string

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my @list = qw/
    AB,CD,EF
    GH,IJ
    KL,MN,OP,UV
    WX
    YZ,123,456,789
/;

my $input = '0 3 4';
my @input = $input =~ /\d+/g;

my $result = join ',', @list[@input];

say $result;
```

#### output

```
AB,CD,EF,WX,YZ,123,456,789
```